# ToUpper/Lower vs Unsafe

Tags: c#, unsafe

Думаю всем известно что строки (`System.String`) неизменяемые по своей природе. Поэтому часто работа с такими методами, как `string.ToUpper()` и прочими, порождает новый объект, почти идентичный предыдущему.

Я даже не хочу выяснять причины этого, у меня явно ума поменьше чем у ребят, которые придумали такую обертку над массивом `Char`, но все же изменить строки можно, как минимум через указатели.

Написал такой расширяющий метод:

```
public static unsafe String ToUpperUnsafe ( this String value )
{
    fixed ( Char* arrChr = value )
    {
        for ( var i = 0 ; i < value.Length ; ++i )
        {
            var temp = Char.ToUpper( value[ i ] );
            arrChr[ i ] = temp;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Как видно, на вход принимается один объект, изменяется и возвращается без клонирования. Вопрос в том, насколько это безопасно. Смотрел бегло исходники оригинального метода, там много всего, что я не понял, из-за этого возникла мысль, что в определенных ситуациях это может не прокатить.

p.s. Кстати ванильный метод работает быстрей, зато этот выигрывает в памяти.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Так делать нельзя.

Дело в том, что весь framework исходит из того, что строки неизменяемы. Поэтому, например, если вы поместите строку в `HashSet`, а потом измените её, вы потом не сможете её оттуда удалить (а вместе с вами и другие куски программы, находящиеся далеко от вас и не знающие, что вы сломали строку).

Метод сортировки, который не учитывает, что у него из-под носа могут заменить значение, имеет право зациклиться бесконечно или вылететь по обращению к неправильному индексу.

Представьте себе, что будет, если строка, которую вы ломаете, интернирована. Тогда каждый, у кого была строковая константа `"abc"`, внезапно без предупреждения получит строковую константу `"ABC"`:

```
string lo = "abc", hi = "ABC";
string villain = "abc";
villain.ToUpperUnsafe();
Console.WriteLine(lo == hi); // true
```

Представьте себе так же, что вы сломаете строку, которая является названием типа. Что произойдёт при попытке применить рефлексию?

Словом, ваш метод привносит в язык undefined behavour, отсутствие которого выгодно отличало C# от C++.

Вся эта катавасия, которую может устроить одна «маленькая» оптимизация, совершенно не стоит выгоды в несколько микросекунд.

Comment: совсем вылетело из головы что строки интернируются, спасибо)

Comment: Строки ненастолько неизменяемые, как кажется. По крайней мере, старая реализация StrungBuilder'а (до .net 4) использовала именно изменяемую строку. Так что вероятно, с внутренней целостностью строки что-то можно сделать. Её внешняя неизменность куда важнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Даже если это так, одно дело локальный, внутренний объект, о котором разработчики языка знают, что именно с ним-то и можно устроить хак. И другое дело — объект, который неизвестно откуда пришёл, и неизвестно, кто и как его ещё использует.

Comment: @VladD, да. Я имел в виду, что можно безопасно менять строку только пока она гарантированно создана тобой. И, возможно, понадобятся дополнительные костыли для сохранения внутренней целостности. Но как только строка попала во внешний код, или если она пришла из него, её менять нельзя.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Причём ввиду интернинга то, что строка пришла _не_ из внешнего кода, вовсе не очевидно. Поскольку компилятор имеет право считать строки неизменными, мы никогда не можем узнать, обманули мы его или нет. Например, он может заинлайнить наш метод, в котором вызывается Upcase, и переставить местами операторы (строка-то считается неизменной для него!). Только разработчик языка можно быть уверен на все сто, что строка независима, и её можно «портить».

Comment: @VladD, я сказал "гарантированно создана тобой". Интернируются только константные строки и результаты операций с ними, пустая строка независимо от способа её получения (в том числе через явный вызов new) и результаты явного интернирования через String.Intern.

Comment: Любая непустая строка созданная через new является уникальной. В каком месте, какой обман и какого именно оптимизатора ты видишь?

Answer (score 6):

> Вопрос в том, насколько это безопасно.

Да вообще небезопасно.

> Думаю всем известно что строки (System.String) неизменяемые по своей природе. ... Я даже не хочу выяснять причины этого

Зря не хочешь. Представь всё, что записывается литералами. Это числа. В VB ещё даты. Всё это value-типы.

```
int x = 50;
x.Add(10); // Ну представим, что такой метод есть
int y = 50;
// Ну ты же не ждёшь, что теперь y равен 60?
```

Аналогично со строками:

```
string s = "abc";
s.ToUpper();
string t = "abc"; // Упс.. Твоя реализация сделает t = "ABC"
```

По-моему, одного этого достаточно, чтобы никогда твой метод не использовать.

А теперь, почему же reference-тип? Да это просто оптимизация - не надо копировать огромные строки при каждой передаче. Мы просто не меняем оригинал, поэтому семантически нет разницы между value и reference. А вот если мы хотим поменять, то надо создать новую строку.

Answer (score 0):

Вы только что изобрели велосипед :), используя unsafe, вместо класса [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), созданный именно для представления изменяемых строк.

Comment: Я в курсе про данный класс, на данный момент меня интересует один объект против двух и безопасность данного метода, а не целесообразность)